# Compare request.path with a reversed url in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I understand that `request.path` will give me the current URL.

I am currently working on my `base.html` template with CSS tabs and I want the template to know which tab is currently "active" and pass `class="active-tab"` to an `<a>` tag.

So I wanted to do something like

```
<a href="{% url orders_list %}"
    {% if request.path = reverse('orders_list') %}
        class="active-tab"
    {$ endif %}
>Orders</a>
```

But I'm sure you can't do that `if` comparison. I also only want the base (?) URL ignoring any GET parameters.

Any suggestions or tips also welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def active(request, pattern):
    path = request.path
    if path == pattern:
        return 'active'
    return ''
```

Then usage is sort of like this in your template:

```
{% load my_tags %}

{% url orders_list as orders %}
<li class="{% active request orders %}"> 
    <a href="{{ orders }}"> Orders </a> 
</li>
```

You can modify the template tag as you wish.

Answer (score 20):

Building on Josh's answer, you can use a simple 'if' tag:

```
{% url 'orders_list' as orders_list_url %}
<a{% if request.path == orders_list_url %} class="active"{% endif %}
  href="{{ orders_list_url }}">Orders</a>
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer since it is the easiest way to achieve the desired result. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

A better version of the top answer would be to reverse the viewname:

```
{% url_active 'reverse_viewname' %}
```

This version doesn't require you to pass in the `request`.  Instead, we indicate that the tag needs the context and then get the request from that.

```
from django import template
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_active(context, viewname):
    request = context['request']
    current_path = request.path
    compare_path = reverse(viewname)
    if current_path == compare_path:
        return 'active'
    else:
        return ''
```

Answer (score 2):

Usage: `{% url_active "home" "other-view" "and-so-on" success="active-specific-class" %}`

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def url_active(context, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'request' not in context:
        return ''

    request = context['request']
    if request.resolver_match.url_name in args:
        return kwargs['success'] if 'success' in kwargs else 'active'
    else:
        return ''
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution with an if-then-else option:

```
from django import template
from django.template.base import Node, NodeList, TemplateSyntaxError

register = template.Library()

class IfCurrentViewNode(Node):
    child_nodelists = ('nodelist_true', 'nodelist_false')

    def __init__(self, view_name, nodelist_true, nodelist_false):
        self.view_name = view_name
        self.nodelist_true, self.nodelist_false = nodelist_true, nodelist_false

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<IfCurrentViewNode>"

    def render(self, context):
        view_name = self.view_name.resolve(context, True)
        request = context['request']
        if request.resolver_match.url_name == view_name:
            return self.nodelist_true.render(context)
        return self.nodelist_false.render(context)


def do_ifcurrentview(parser, token):
    bits = token.split_contents()
    if len(bits) < 2:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError("'%s' takes at least one argument"
                                  " (path to a view)" % bits[0])
    view_name = parser.compile_filter(bits[1])
    nodelist_true = parser.parse(('else', 'endifcurrentview'))
    token = parser.next_token()
    if token.contents == 'else':
        nodelist_false = parser.parse(('endifcurrentview',))
        parser.delete_first_token()
    else:
        nodelist_false = NodeList()
    return IfCurrentViewNode(view_name, nodelist_true, nodelist_false)

@register.tag
def ifcurrentview(parser, token):
    """
    Outputs the contents of the block if the current view match the argument.

    Examples::

        {% ifcurrentview 'path.to.some_view' %}
            ...
        {% endifcurrentview %}

        {% ifcurrentview 'path.to.some_view' %}
            ...
        {% else %}
            ...
        {% endifcurrentview %}
    """
    return do_ifcurrentview(parser, token)
```

Comment: ur code works great. Is there a way to write some simple test case for this? I want to maintain our test coverage percentage. Wrote a SO question for exactly this request at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534145/how-to-write-a-test-case-for-this-django-custom-tag

Comment: I guess it's testable. Don't know how. You should take a look at how Django tests its tags (e.g. https://github.com/django/django/blob/3c447b108ac70757001171f7a4791f493880bf5b/tests/template_tests/tests.py#L104)

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate whatever you need (`request.path = reverse('orders_list')` for example) in your view and pass the result to the template. In the view (python code) you can manipulate the path as much as you like.

You can check if one URL is the prefix of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try this jQuery statement:

```
$("[href='{{ request.path }}']").parents("li").addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by cougar's answer:

```
$("ul.nav [href='"+window.location.pathname+"']").parents("li").addClass('active');
```

This solution is plain JS, and works for Bootstrap's navigation bar. For the OP's scenario one can use:

```
$("[href='"+window.location.pathname+"']").addClass('active-tab');
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a hacked way to do it in jQuery... but I'm still open for a better solution.

jQuery:

```
var tab_list = {
    'orders-tab' : '{% url orders_list %}',
    'users-tab'  : '{% url users_list %}',
    'vendors-tab': '{% url vendors_list %}',
    'places-tab' : '{% url places_list %}'
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var property in tab_list) {
        if('{{ request.path }}' == tab_list[property]) {
            $('#' + property).addClass('active-tab')
            break
        }
    }
})
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="tabs" class="fl">
    <li><a href="#" id="dashboard-tab" class="dashboard-tab">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url orders_list %}" id="orders-tab">Orders</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url users_list %}" id="users-tab">Users</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url vendors_list %}" id="vendors-tab">Vendors</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url places_list %}" id="places-tab">Places</a></li>
</ul>
```