# Remove links to current page in Django tamplate

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a Django template (list.html), which includes these links

```
  <a href="{% url 'notifications:list' %}" role="button">All</a> |
  <a href="{% url 'notifications:list_unread' %}" role="button">Unread</a> |
  <a href="{% url 'notifications:read_all' %}" role="button">Mark all read</a>
```

two of those views (notifications:list & notifications:list_unread) use this template, but send a different queryset to be displayed.

How can I use Django template language to remove the link to the current view?

For example, if I was on the "list" view, I would see:

Unread | Mark all read

If I was on the 'list_unread' view, I would see:

All | Mark all read

Or is there a better way to do this? It seems like it would be common task.

Comment: Your question is not very clear about what problem you try to solve. What do you mean `disable` the link to current view? Or are you saying you have trouble reusing one template for `list` and `list_unread`?

Comment: I mean, if they are on the "Unread" page, I don't want the "Unread" link to be clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it right within the template, showing the first two links as conditional:

```
  {% url 'notifications:list' as list_url %}
  {% if request.path != list_url %}
    <a href="{{list_url}}">All</a> |
  {% endif %}
  {% url 'notifications:list_unread' as list_unread_url %}
  {% if request.path != list_unread_url %}
    <a href="list_unread_url" >Unread</a> |
  {% endif %}
  <a href="{% url 'notifications:read_all' %}">Mark all read</a>
```

h/t: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17311506/2700631

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a variable into `context` and check this is in your template to disable either of the link.

**Notification List View:**

In your notifications list view, you can pass a variable `notifications_list` to your template.

```
class NotificationsListView(..):

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super(NotificationListView).get_context_data()
        context['notifications_list'] = True
        return context
```

Then in your template you can do something like:

```
{% if not notifications_list %}
    <a href="{% url 'notifications:list' %}" role="button">All</a> |
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'notifications:list_unread' %}" role="button">Unread</a> |
{% endif %}
<a href="{% url 'notifications:read_all' %}" role="button">Mark all read</a>
```

So, whenever there is a request for notifications list view, the `list` link will be disabled and the `list_unread` link will be shown.

In case of `list_unread` request, the `list` link will be shown and `list_unread` link will not be shown.